# Android key accumulation problem?

Tags: android

I have problem with key:

When my App is loading, i press back key many times (about 20 times). 
Via logcat, sometime i see:

```
Key pressed - back key 
Key Released - back key
Key pressed - back key
Key Released - back key
```

And sometime no log here. but when load finish, i'' see:

```
Key pressed - back key 
Key Released - back key
Key pressed - back key
Key Released - back key
Key pressed - back key 
Key Released - back key
Key pressed - back key
Key Released - back key
...
enough 20 times
```

look like the phone save it to buffer :(

An the question, How can i remove this buffer? :((

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just override `onBackPressed()` and don't call `super` if your activity hasn't finished loading?

Comment: It's impossible. Because, when my app's loading, i press back key but phone doesn't process or just process a part. (i guess because i don't see the log from onKeyDown, Up function when i pressed in loading time)
But when finished, i see the log from these function displayed continuously. 

So, if i overwrite and set the conditions like that, it only useful for the part processed in loading time, how about rest part :(